# Error:(20,0)Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection]

Tags: android-studio

Below are my gradle files..
so here is the error which i get when i sync the project:-Error:(20, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
Open File

Following is my app gradle...

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sinch.workshopskeleton"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.3.5.jar')
}
```

Following is my project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('app/libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.11.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: You only posted one image.  And please copy and paste the actual code not an image of it.

Comment: sorry actually I am new here so I was finding difficult to post it...Now i guess it is in the correct format...

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** below lines from your **project's build gradle** and it will work fine.
You can add this in your app level build gradle.

```
dependencies {
    compile files('app/libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.11.1.jar')
}
```